# VSCode exception has occurred: CLR/System.ApplicationException

Tags: c#, azure, exception, visual-studio-code, speech-to-text

I'm working on a Speech to Text model using C# in VSCode. The model transcribes the first file correctly. When I add a new file and attempt to transcribe, I get the following error:

Exception has occurred: CLR/System.ApplicationException
An exception of type 'System.ApplicationException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code: 'Exception with an error code: 0x8 (SPXERR_FILE_OPEN_FAILED)'
at Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Internal.SpxExceptionThrower.ThrowIfFail(IntPtr hr)
at Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Recognizer.FromConfig(GetRecognizerFromConfigDelegate fromConfig, SpeechConfig speechConfig, AudioConfig audioConfig)
at Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.SpeechRecognizer..ctor(SpeechConfig speechConfig, AudioConfig audioConfig)
at NEST.Program.d__1.MoveNext() in C:\Users\admin\source\repos\AI-102-Process-Speech-master\transcribe_speech_to_text\csharp\NEST\Program.cs:line 26
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at NEST.Program.d__0.MoveNext() in C:\Users\admin\source\repos\AI-102-Process-Speech-master\transcribe_speech_to_text\csharp\NEST\Program.cs:line 12

The await RecognizeSpeechAsync(); part is where the exception occurs (line 12).
Line 26 is using (var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(config, audioInput)).

My code is:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech;
using Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech.Audio;

namespace NEST
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            await RecognizeSpeechAsync();
        }

        static async Task RecognizeSpeechAsync()
        {
            // Configure the subscription information for the service to access.
            // Use either key1 or key2 from the Speech Service resource you have created
            var config = SpeechConfig.FromSubscription("subscriptionkeyx", "regionx");

            // Setup the audio configuration, in this case, using a file that is in local storage.
            using (var audioInput = AudioConfig.FromWavFileInput("C:/Users/admin/source/repos          /AI-102-Process-Speech-master/transcribe_speech_to_text/media/whatstheweatherlike.wav"))

            // Pass the required parameters to the Speech Service which includes the configuration
            // and the audio file name that you will use as input
            using (var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(config, audioInput))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Recognizing first result...");
                var result = await recognizer.RecognizeOnceAsync();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The sample code of the previous post was created by vs2019, and the one in this post was created by vscode. Please be patient and try it together. Let's determine where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

## `SPXERR_FILE_OPEN_FAILED` means file not found or open failed.

I added a space in the file path to reproduce your problem. (You are using an absolute path.)

*Error path：*

```
C:/Users/Administrator/source/repos   /vscodeConsole/narration.wav
```

[image]

*Correct path*

```
C:/Users/Administrator/source/repos/vscodeConsole/narration.wav
```

[image]

**PRIVIOUS**

**Looking at the error message, there is an error near Line 26.**

[You can test with my sample code](https://github.com/Jason446620/recognizespeeck-dotnetcore). If it runs normally, then it is a problem with your code. My preliminary judgment is that the code near your file path is abnormal.

[image]

If my sample code does not run normally, it may be caused by the installation of VSCode (including Extension) or dotnet core, and further TroubleShooting is required.

Comment: Apologies, the space in the code is due to my formatting error when posting to stackoverflow. The space is not present in the actual code.

Comment: @MichaelSchwartz Does my sample code works in your local

Comment: @MichaelSchwartz pls upload you sample code without any sensitive information, and tell us which version of vscode you use , and which version of .net core you installed?

Comment: The issue was resolved. It only occurred when I ran the project from the integrated terminal using the dotnet run command. When I select Ctrl+F5 the project runs successfully. I swapped files and it correctly transcribed the second one with no errors. Thanks for your help!